# Remove the border of UITableView, not separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to remove the border of `UITableView`, by default there's a gray line between the cells and around the table.  Note I just want to delete the border around the table not the separators between the cells.

I've searched but only find answers that delete all the lines.  This code deleted all the borders around and between the cells and table:

```
self.table.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

This code did not work, nothing happens:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
self.table.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

My table is a grouped table view, by default in the xib, and the separator is single line.

Comment: Did you tried self.table.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f ?

Comment: yep.still nothing happens

Comment: Ok, maybe it's the cell border. Did you try to do the same for the cell views?

Comment: you mean delete the top of the first cell  and the bottom of the last?

Comment: No, do something like cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f. Maybe this line is because of the cell (Can't believe it, but it worth trying).

As I understand, you want to delete all the borders of the table view, except the separator. right?

Comment: yeah,i want only the separators between the cells. i've tried set the borderwidth of the cell. still nothing happens.. >_<

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, what I have done is remove the border and added a custom separator using Imageview at the bottom of custom TableViewCell.

Comment: may be there is some elegant way, but I am not able to find it out. Let me know if found some other way.

Comment: I did this in the same way, because didn't find more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
self.yourTableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set tebleview border witdth = 0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this solution...

```
self.table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.table.backgroundView = nil;
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score -5):

Pleae try:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```